# Can you make it so a chart color gradient color changes with a cell value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am curious if it is possible to make a two colored gradient bubble to have its colors dependent on cell values / colors.

I have a bubble graph where I want to have each bubble two different colors via a gradient.  Each half of the bubble color is dependent on the color of a cell.  It would make for less errors if the colors of the bubbles were autofilled based off the color in two cells.

Is something like this possible to do?

[image: Bubble graph photo]

Comment: Is `Format Data Series -> Series Options -> Vary colors by point` what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi!  I don't see that as an option when I select my series.

Comment: You are using Excel 2016 or 365? and are you right-clicking on the series to access `Format Data Series`? https://imgur.com/a/Ww9Wjrm

Comment: I am using Excel 365.  When I right click that option is not even listed (thought it might be greyed out, but its not even there).  Could it be because it is a bubble chart and not a scatter?

Comment: I deleted a series and now that option is available.  I will play around with that and see if it works.